# Tempo alteration "retard" instead of "ritard"

Tags: terminology, tempo

So, this is a piece I'm working on with a large chorus of youngsters ages 10-12.  I've never seen a tempo alteration spelled this way.  Is it something distinct from "ritard?"  Is it simply an unfortunate typo?  It appears in Randall Thompson's "Some One," which is part of the larger set Two Childhood Songs.

[image]

Comment: Are the other written indications, such as "mysteriously" also in English? If yes, then that's why: retard is the English equivalent of the Italian ritard.

Comment: @Aaron - agree… & for those not too familiar with it in pre-21st century English, it's also pronounced 'rit**ard**' not '**ree**tard', especially these days because of the PC/woke connotations. It's another word 'lost' to the English language because it gained a new popular meaning. Life & language moves on… [It did keep the 'ree' in retardation, oddly]

Comment: @Tetsujin Having read too many french scores I’d intuitively pronounce this quite differently!

Answer (score 6):

In music, a 'Retardation' is a suspension that resolves upwards.

'Ritardando' or 'rit.' is a slowing-down.

'Retard' is, I think, merely a misprint.  And even if it isn't, we should probably avoid it, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Especially in music printed for 11 year-olds!

Answer (score 2):

"Retard" is not a misprint, but is used here as an English verb in place of the Italian *ritardando* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retard): "to slow up ... to undergo retardation").

There was a movement in the mid-twentieth century to use the composer's native language instead of conventional musical directions from other languages. Percy Grainger exemplifies this in the extreme, replacing *p* and *pp* with "soft" and "very soft," or *crescendo* with "get louder." Here Thompson doesn't go quite as far and still uses *ppp*, but uses an English word for the tempo change.

Comment: My understanding is that movement well pre-dated the twentieth century. Bach is generally credited with being the first, and Beethoven also gets credit. By the Romantic era, it was pretty common to see instructions in French or German according to the language of the composer.

Comment: I back Aaron up here - Robert Schumann *loved* his German tempo markings, and I'm fairly sure I've seen at least one instruction in a Claude Debussy work in French.

Comment: @Aaron which Bach piece uses German tempo markings?  I can't think of any (having tried for all of 10 or 15 seconds).  Was it J. S. Bach or one of his descendants?  I'm less familiar with Beethoven's output but the few pieces I know use Italian liberally (_sonata quasi una fantasia, ritmo de tre battute_).  Later in the 19th century, sure, _langsam_ and _mässig bewegt_ and the like rule the day.

Comment: @phoog I think I confused Bach's use of German texts as opposed to musical instructions. Beethoven did use some German instruction. An example chosen at random: Opus. 109, 2nd mvmt begins "Gesangvoll, mit innigster Empfindung." [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No.30,_Op.109_(Beethoven,_Ludwig_van)) has a holograph, the instruction is on page 21 of the PDF.

Comment: @Aaron Of course, and especially in the earliest days of early music, there was a lot of vernacular. And I feel like the French have always had their own stubborn thing about sticking to French (Lully, *piu fort*, etc.); thus while "universal" expression terms are Italian, bowing terms like *detaché* are French.

Comment: @Aaron  I kept starting to put in a sentence about *why* there was this renewed push in the mid-20th-century, but stopped short since I don't know enough. I feel like it was a mix of pre- and post-WW2 nationalism, and maybe the same kind of futurist reformist zeal that lead George Bernard Shaw to try to ["reform" English spelling](http://spellingsociety.org/uploaded_books/a9spelling.pdf); a kind of "simplification" that ultimately obfuscates because we're too used to a convention.

Comment: Grainger's use of English markings in his scores, as opposed to Italian, stems from his idea that pre-Norman England was a superior "Nordic" culture that had been corrupted by Norman & Latin influences.  He tried to develop what he called "blue-eyed English" to compensate.  All I can say to that is "yikes".

Comment: I wonder what Grainger called a piano. I know he was an accomplished softist.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the Beethoven example. It's interesting that it seems to be squeezed between the Italian instruction and the staff.  I can't tell if they're both in Beethoven's hand since it was traditional to use different lettering styles to write German and romance languages.  I'm not convinced that the first word is "gesangvoll," however.

Comment: @Aaron Do you mean Bach's use of German texts as in the texts the singers were singing?  In church? That was an innovation of Martin Luther nearly two centuries before Bach.  Heinrich Schütz, born 100 years before Bach, has a huge body of German-language liturgical music, and the German church cantata was a well developed form by the time J.S. came on the scene. Andy Bonner: Lully was born Giovanni Battista Lulli.  He moved to France in his teens.  The French were not uniquely "stubborn" in this regard, though; Purcell used English tempo indications.  I don't know about others of that time.

Comment: @phoog Yes! Lully is such an paradigm of Frenchness that everybody forgets that, like so much else, he was "imported from Italy." And yeah, there's plenty of English in Purcell, Playford, Eccles, et al. And that's kind of the point; Italian *wasn't* so universal yet the way it was in the 19th century, making the 20th-century-nationalist trends a distinction.

Comment: @AndyBonner indeed.  But I wonder why the Germans took to Italian so early on.  Maybe it's because they were using tempo indications primarily in Italian forms such as sonatas -- I also found a Purcell sonata with Italian indications.  The "slow" I found yesterday was in a theater piece if I recall correctly.  I'll have to look at some other pieces by Buxtehude and Pachelbel (if manuscripts exist) and see whether they have tempo indications.  Schütz and his contemporaries were, I think, too early.